# Xcode freezes in build after adding constraints to a views label

Tags: swift, xcode, build

I am building a simple app and I am creating all the UI in code. The project worked fine until I added the constraints for some labels and add some stuff to the storyboard (I found the storyboard useful for wireframeing).

Now when I try to build, the build freezes (Xcode still responds to input) during the compiling of Swift files.

Before (when the project would build), my class looked like this:

```
class CurrentWeatherView: UIView {

    weak var tempLowLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var tempLowIcon: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var tempHighLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var tempHighIcon: UILabel! = UILabel()

    weak var precipChanceLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var precipIconLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var humidity: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var humidityIconLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()

    weak var icon: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var tempLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()

    weak var summaryLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var summaryScroll: UIScrollView! = UIScrollView()
}
```

Now (when it won't build), it looks like this:

```
class CurrentWeatherView: UIView {

    weak var tempLowLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var tempLowIcon: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var tempHighLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var tempHighIcon: UILabel! = UILabel()

    weak var precipChanceLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var precipIconLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var humidityLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var humidityIconLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()

    weak var icon: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var iconSummaryLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var tempLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()

    weak var summaryLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    weak var summaryScroll: UIScrollView! = UIScrollView()

    func setUpLayout() {

        self.addSubview(tempLowLabel)
        self.addSubview(tempLowIcon)
        self.addSubview(tempHighLabel)
        self.addSubview(tempHighIcon)
        self.addSubview(precipChanceLabel)
        self.addSubview(precipIconLabel)
        self.addSubview(humidityLabel)
        self.addSubview(humidityIconLabel)
        self.addSubview(icon)
        self.addSubview(iconSummaryLabel)
        self.addSubview(tempLabel)
        self.addSubview(summaryLabel)
        self.addSubview(summaryScroll)

        tempLowLabel.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false
        tempLowIcon.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false
        tempHighLabel.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false
        tempHighIcon.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false
        precipChanceLabel.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false
        precipIconLabel.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false
        humidityLabel.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false
        humidityIconLabel.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false
        icon.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false
        iconSummaryLabel.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false
        tempLabel.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false
        summaryLabel.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false
        summaryScroll.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempHighIcon, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 12),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempHighIcon, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 22),
                tempHighIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22),
                tempHighIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),

                NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempLowIcon, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 12),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempLowIcon, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tempHighIcon, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5),
                tempLowIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22),
                tempLowIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),

                NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempHighLabel, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tempHighIcon, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempHighLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 22),
                tempHighIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22),
                tempHighIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 42),

                NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempLowLabel, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tempLowIcon, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempLowLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: tempHighLabel, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5),
                tempHighIcon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22),
                tempHighIcon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 42),

                NSLayoutConstraint(item: icon, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 22),
                icon.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
                icon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 85),
                icon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 85),

                iconSummaryLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: icon.centerXAnchor),
                iconSummaryLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: icon.centerYAnchor),
                iconSummaryLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75),
                iconSummaryLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75),

                NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: icon, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8),
                tempLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
                tempLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 85),
                tempLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25),

                NSLayoutConstraint(item: summaryScroll, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 12),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: summaryScroll, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 12),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: summaryScroll, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8),
                summaryScroll.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 21),
                summaryScroll.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),

                NSLayoutConstraint(item: precipChanceLabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 12),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: precipChanceLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 22),
                precipChanceLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22),
                precipChanceLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 42),

                NSLayoutConstraint(item: humidityLabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 12),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: humidityLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: precipChanceLabel, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5),
                humidityLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22),
                humidityLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 42),

                NSLayoutConstraint(item: precipIconLabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: precipChanceLabel, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: precipIconLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 22),
                precipIconLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22),
                precipIconLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),

                NSLayoutConstraint(item: humidityIconLabel, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: humidityLabel, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: humidityIconLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: precipIconLabel, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5),
                humidityIconLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 22),
                humidityIconLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),
            ])
    }
}
```

Are all those constraints to much for Xcode?

Also, indexing doesn't complete.

I have tried cleaning the project, cleaning the build folder, removing the derived data, re-booting my machine, restarting Xcode, updating Xcode and checked code optimization level, but none of it helped.

Comment: (1) I've learned to let Xcode alone when I see "indexing....". Grab a cup of your favorite beverage, bounce around online, take a nap, whatever. Just don't interrupt it. :-) (2) I'm curious why you are setting all your UIKit vars to weak. While that's the IBOutlet default, I never declare mine that way - that doesn't mean my way is any more correct, it's just a major difference.

Comment: @dfd The reason I chose weak was for two reasons: 1) IBOutlets are declared that way so I thought that was the way you are supposed to do it. 2) I thought it would help with memory. Is there are specific reason you do it? Also, what is indexing and why should I not mess with it?

Comment: The number of constraints here are nothing noteworthy. Xcode can and should be able to handle this (and much much more).

Comment: I code the way I've always seen - while I rarely used Obj-C, even there too. I can't give you any better reason than that. You claim Xcode is "freezing" when trying to build - I don't doubt that so I'm looking at things that could be the issue. As for indexing, I remember seeing somewhere (maybe here) a comment to the effect of "let Xcode do whatever it is when you see indexing". I've had it happen to me... I couldn't understand why I couldn't build and tried everything from rebooting to unplugging my device, etc., only to find things didn't work.

Comment: @dfd Sorry. I explained this the wrong way. The _build_ freezes. Xcode does not. Note my edit to the explanation. >the build freezes (Xcode still responds to input)

Comment: That's exactly how my builds behaved when Xcode was indexing. I never found out what this indexing is doing - and it feels to me like it's related to plugging in a physical device, as I don't recall seeing this happen without that. But I go back to my original comment... if Xcode is indexing, just leave it alone. It may be minutes (one time I remember it being several, almost 10) but someone else said "there's nothing you can do". EDIT: When I speak of the behavior, I mean that it isn't building, a second task appears because it's still indexing, I **can** quit Xcode, add code - but not build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by updating to Xcode version 8.3 beta. Xcode 8.3 was just released so that should work also.